# React-router not rendering the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a nested route that is not rendering the passed Component.

In my app.js I have a router setup like this and all works perfectly

```
<Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={NavBar} />
          </Switch>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Drawer} />
          </Switch>
          <div className="Content">
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
</Router>
```

then I have a sidedrawer which has a NavLink like this and it redirects perfectly

```
<NavLink to="/dashboard/table">
  <Description className={classes.icon} />
</NavLink>
```

and then i also have in Dashboard.js a line like this

```
<Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path={`${this.props.match.url}/table`}
        component={DataTable}
      />
</Switch>
```

when i click the Icon in the sidedrawer it should redirect to /dashboard/table and render the DataTable Component but it just redirects and it doesnt render anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use withRouter hoc in the component, it will solve your issue.
Something like below:

```
import { withRouter, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
cosnt MyComponent = () => {
  return (<Router>
    <App />
  </Router>)
}
const App = () => {
  return (...all other routes)
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: add withRouter to main component in which all routes are return, not in the child routings

Comment: this means to the App.js or Dashboard.js ? If i add it to App.js i get an error that i should not use withRouter outside of Router